# change values of Autoincrement ID on mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to change the values of the ID based on different categories on my product table on mysql

for an example-

tshirts will use an ID of TS00XXX
shorts will use an ID of SH00XXX

I am using a form to add the products to the table so that you can select different categories based on that.

I am using php and mysql, if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Show your code, what you do

Comment: Too broad. Flagging for close. Welcome to Stack Overflow, but you need to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best possible solution would be, Leave ID integer and Auto-Increment.

Create new field called "product_type" which either 'TS' ,'SH' or any other types you might have to store.

while retrieving you can always user concat function, in this case

```
select concat(product_type, id) as product_id, * where product_id = 'SHXXX'
```

returns product_id 'TSXXX' or 'SHXXX'

or get id by product

```
select * where product_type = 'SH' and id = XXX
```

Comment: sounds like a good idea, i shall try that out.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

best way is to create another table for product ids and get the id value for every time inserting data into main products table, after inserting increment the id value by one this is simplest way..

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
// function to generate random ID number
function createID() {
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $id .= rand(0,9);
 }
 return $id;
}

// MySQL connect info
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $pass,$dbase);
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM products");

// puts all known ID numbers into $ids array
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
 $ids[] = $result["id"];
}

// generates random ID number
$id = createID();

// while the new ID number is found in the $ids array, generate a new $id number
while (in_array("SH00".$id,$ids) || in_array("TS00".$id,$ids)) {
 $id = createID();
}

// Now Add  TS00 or SH00 
$id="SH00".$id;
echo $id;
```